# Passing parameters by clicking on images in ruby on rails on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I am developing a ruby on rails application for a hackathon and am stuck in the part of creating a like/dislike option. Basically, I have two images and on clicking one of them a certain string, lets say "a" should be passed to the next page. If the other image is clicked, "b" should be passed.I have no previous ruby on rails experience. Could someone please answer this? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a HTML question than ruby. You can use a HTML a tag to achieve this

```
<a id="like" href="http://somewhere.com/like?q=1"> </a>
```

then in CSS you can style it so which ever image you want is displayed.

If you would like to do this dynamically, you can use a javascript click handler and then do a get request to the appropriate controller

Comment: Actually these values are supposed to be passed to the controller and then sent to the database to modify the like/dislike count of that particular item. So I'm looking for a way to pass parameters after an image is clicked...

Comment: Then you could use javascript to send the data to the appropriate controller using AJAX

Comment: @WendelinThewierd.. this is the way rails handle the request, every request is sent to the controller#action and thats where you can do whatever you want to do with it, say it be saving to database or keeping in session or redirecting somewhere.